# PHP Put matching data from second array at the top of the first array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
1-  
    Array ( [55] => latest 
            [2] => block2 
            [3] => featured 
            [56] => News 
            [4] => portfolio 
            [57] => archive  )
```

and another one that it's built with the user choices and it looks like this: ie.

```
2-   Array ( [0] => 56 
             [1] => 55 
             [2] => 4)
```

so there's 3 Id's from array one are chosen, what i'm trying to do is to have those values on array (2) to reordered in the first array so the array looks like this;

```
3- /*results*/ 

    Array ( [56] => News 
            [55] => latest 
            [4] => portfolio 
            [2] => block2 
            [3] => featured  
            [57] => archive  )
```

if you see that i should change anything in the array structure to get or any solution , please let me know.

Comment: Your first and third arrays are absolutely identical. The indeces and data are preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

arr1 =

```
Array ( [55] => latest 
        [2] => block2 
        [3] => featured 
        [56] => News 
        [4] => portfolio 
        [57] => archive  )
```

arr2 =

```
Array ( [0] => 56 
         [1] => 55 
         [2] => 4)

foreach($arr1 as $key1 => $val1)
{
    foreach($arr2 as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        if($val2 == $key1)
            $arr3[$val2] = $val1;
    }
}
print_r($arr3);
```

it will give you

Comment: Thanx GautamD, but it returns this; Array ( [55] => latest [56] => News [4] => portfolio )

Comment: missing the rest of the list from the first array , and notes that the ordering isn't the same as is i want.

Comment: this-------- Array ( [55] => latest [56] => News [4] => portfolio )

Comment: ok;  krsort($arr1, SORT_NUMERIC);  sorted it but still not what i want,, i need that array-3 holds the full list, how i should do that

Comment: I have given for getting similer elemnts in both arrays and if you want for rem elements you can give them seperatly after my code